# Make Random.range not repeat values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to spawn different objects and it's crucial that no two objects get repeated. What I mean is, random.range should not get two simultaneous numbers same, otherwise the code spawns same objects sometimes. Here's a simpler code to help you understand what I'm trying.

```
void Update () {

    j = Random.Range (1, 4); // this should give j values like=(1,2,1,3,2,1)
                              // and not this = (1,1,2,2...) the numbers should not repeat simultaneously.

    Inst();
}

void Inst(){

    if (j == 1) {

        //instantiate obj1
    }
    else if (j == 2) {

        instantiate obj2
    }

    else if (j == 3) {

        instantiate obj3
    }


}
```

Thank You!

Comment: keep track of the previous value, don't let it generate that value on the next go

Comment: It's look like you are searching for [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273313/4685428)

Comment: How should I do that? Compare everytime using if?

Comment: Use Recursion. Every time a random number is generated, add it to a List<int>. If theList.Contains() your random number, recurse your function until a new, unique, number is produced.

Comment: @BrandonMiller then he will never end up with a result like `1,2,1,3,2` (which is an acceptable outcome per his post) he doesn't want a result like this `1,1,2,3,1`

Comment: Okay, then instead of adding your int to a list, just declare one int and set it every time the function is called. That way it will never be the same thing twice in a row, but will allow for repeated numbers later on.

Comment: Beware of using `while` loop in the accepted answer to do this. See duplicate for how to do this without a while loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
int lastValue;
public int UniqueRandomInt(int min, int max)
{
    int val = Random.Range(min, max);
    while(lastValue == val)
    {
        val = Random.Range(min, max);
    }
    lastValue = val;
    return val;
}

void Update() 
{
    UniqueRandomInt(1, 4);
    Inst();
}

void Inst()
{
    if (lastValue == 1)
    {
        //instantiate obj1
    }
    else if (lastValue == 2)
    {
        //instantiate obj2
    }
    else if (lastValue == 3)
    {
        //instantiate obj3
    }
}
```

Comment: this will become slow for large lists.

Comment: @Wouter:Realised that. Updated answer.

Comment: alternating sequences are valid?

Comment: Okay, when I use this which variable should I use to compare it in the spawn function?

Comment: Alternating sequences are valid. It's just two numbers should not be repeated simultaneously.

Comment: Might be worth adding a fail-safe check to insure that the numbers passed in for `min` and `max` have a range greater than 1.

Comment: I don't know why this has so many upvotes. It can lead to many serous issues so such game freezing or even locking. Don't use random number to control a `while` loop unless you are in a coroutine function and you wait for some frames.

Answer (score 2):

Your original statement picks 1 out of 3 possible numbers (1, 2, 3).

```
j = Random.Range(1, 4);
```

If you want to avoid the last issued number, then that leaves only 2 possible numbers.

```
Random.Range(1, 3)
```

Adding this random number to the previous value of `j` results in a new value that is equally random, but guaranteed to be different from the previous value of `j`.

```
j = j + Random.Range(1, 3);
```

Of course, you need to wrap values to keep them within the required range {1, 2, 3}:

```
if (j > 3) j -= 3;
```

Alternatively, use modulo (`%`) to make it a one-liner:

```
j = 1 + (j + Random.Range(0, 2)) % 3;
```

Works equally well for bigger ranges.

```
j = min + (j - min + Random.Range(1, max - min)) % (max - min);
```

This approach is more efficient than 'looping while duplicate'; there is no guaranteed limit to the number of iterations.